# Read large json(>5gb) file by line by line and process each line and create DataFrame using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading the file line by line and processing each line.But i am not getting the output i need.

**inputfile.txt**

```
{"M":{"1":"data","2":"esf"},"D":{"4":12312,"6":"err"},"R":{"33":"eres","wer":454}}
{"M":{"1":"a","2":"2"},"D":{"4":3456,"6":"esrr"},"R":{"33":"esre","wer":447}}
{"M":{"1":"data3","2":"fer"},"D":{"4":9873,"6":"errs"},"R":{"33":"eret","wer":189,"55":"rt"}}
```

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd;
import json
with open("inputfile.txt") as f:
  for line in f:
    data=(json.loads(f))
    d=[{k1+k2:v2 for k2,v2 in v1.items()} for k1,v1 in data.items()]
    keys=[k for x in d for k in x.items()]
    keys=list(set(keys))
    df=pd.DataFrame(d,columns=keys)
    print (df)
```

**Output I need:**

```
M1,M2,D4,D6,R33,Rwer,R55
data,esf,12312,err,eres,454,NA
a,2,3456,esrr,esre,447,NA
data3,fer,9873,errs,eret,189,rt
```

Comment: First of all that's not a correct `json` format.

Comment: edited the input json and intended the code.

Comment: Do you need to build an in-memory dataframe (as you title could mean) or just to build a csv file (what your output suggests)?

Comment: To build a csv file.

Comment: @SergeBallesta - what in case if its a single line json ? imagine 10gb single line json, is there an approach in pandas to parse such huge single line jsons ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
with open("inputfile.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        proccess_lines(json.loads(line))
```

Comment: @bharatk i have edited the code and added correct json.

Answer (score 0):

You must read the file once and load each line as a Json string, then use your processing. Code could be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{k1+k2:v2 for k1,v1 in data.items() for k2,v2 in v1.items()} 
                   for data in [json.loads(line) for line in io.StringIO(t)]])
```

This builds a list comprehension containing one dictionary per line, and finally builds a dataframe from it.

With your sample data I get:

```
      D4    D6     M1   M2   R33  R55  Rwer
0  12312   err   data  esf  eres  NaN   454
1   3456  esrr      a    2  esre  NaN   447
2   9873  errs  data3  fer  eret   rt   189
```

If you want to reorder the columns, just use:

```
df[['M1', 'M2', 'D4', 'D6', 'R33', 'Rwer', 'R55']]
```

giving as expected:

```
      M1   M2     D4    D6   R33  Rwer  R55
0   data  esf  12312   err  eres   454  NaN
1      a    2   3456  esrr  esre   447  NaN
2  data3  fer   9873  errs  eret   189   rt
```

Comment: The file is big so json.loads method is taking so much memory and the tool is getting killed.

Comment: so for that i am reading line by line.If i am reading file at a time tool is getting killed on processing json.loads method

Comment: @raam: In my code, each `json.loads` only loads one single line, so what is the exact error?

Answer (score 0):

Extended solution using intermediate Text I/O buffer (acting also as context manager):

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import io

with open('input.json') as f, io.StringIO() as temp_file:
    for line in f:
        d = {}
        json_data = json.loads(line)
        d = {k + sub_k: val for k, inner_d in json_data.items()
             for sub_k, val in inner_d.items()}
        temp_file.write(json.dumps(d) + '\n')
    temp_file.seek(0)

    df = pd.read_json(temp_file, orient='columns', lines=True)
    print(df.to_string())
```

Sample output:

```
      D4    D6     M1   M2   R33  R55  Rwer
0  12312   err   data  esf  eres  NaN   454
1   3456  esrr      a    2  esre  NaN   447
2   9873  errs  data3  fer  eret   rt   189
```